# How I can hover/target elements that are not children with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, hover

I have a sidebar acting like a sidebar menu.

Outside of it, in the main content part, I have another sidebar that I want to reveal when hovering on a menu item. Inside this hidden sidebar I have lots of div's sorted by category. I need to open the panel and display the correct div so when I hover over a menu item, I target the div that has the same data-id. I manage, however I can't cancel the hover effect, the panel remains open.

what I am trying to do :

- When hovering a menu item, the panel opens and shows the related content. The menu item keeps the active class while I'm navigating inside the panel (this is ok) .
- As soon as the mouse goes out of the menu And the panel (on the main body or somewhere else on the sidebar) the panel closes (this is not ok)

[An example](https://designmodo.com/postcards/app/) of what I exactly want to achieve (you have to scroll a little and "skip sign up" to see the page)

```js
$('.component_menu li').hover(function(){
  $('.component_menu li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  $('.modules-panel__list-group').addClass('slide-lr')
  $('.modules-panel__list-group >div').each(function(){
  $(this).hide();
    if($(this).data('id') == id) {
      
      $(this).css('display','block');
      }
    })
})
```

```css
.component_panel{
  background: #fff;
    height: calc(100% - 60px);
    z-index:2;
    padding:10px 0;
    margin:35px 0 0;
}
.component_menu{
  list-style:none;
  z-index:2;
  background-color:#ffffff;
  padding:10px 0;
}
.component_menu li{
  display:block;
  padding:10px;
  cursor:pointer;
  background-color:#ffffff;
}
.component_menu li.active{
  background-color: #eff3f6;
}

.component__logo,
.component__header,
.component__banner,
.component__feature,
.component__cta,
.component__footer{
     display:none;
}


.modules-panel__list-group{
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    left:0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 330px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
   padding-top:50px;
    background-color: #eff3f6;
    visibility: hidden;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .5s;
    will-change: transform,opacity;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow-y: scroll
}
.modules-panel__list-group p{
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.17;
    color: #727c80;
    text-align:left;
}
.modules-panel__list-group>div{
  padding:0 20px;
  text-align:center;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.modules-panel__list-group.slide-lr{
    visibility: visible;
    transform: translateX(225px);
    opacity: 1;
    max-height:600px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="component_menu">
    <ul>
      <li class="component_menuitem-logo" data-id="logo">logo</li>
        <li class="component_menuitem-banner" data-id="banner">banner</li>
        <li class="component_menuitem-spacer" data-id="spacer">spacer</li>
        <li class="component_menuitem-cta" data-id="cta"> cta</li>
        <li class="component_menuitem-content" data-id="content">content</li>
        <li class="component_menuitem-feature" data-id="features">features</li>
        <li class="component_menuitem-footer" data-id="table">footer</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="modules-panel__list-group">
    <div class="component__logo" data-id="logo">
        <button type="button" class="component" id="add-brand-logo-standard-right">
         <p>Brand Logo Standard Rigth</p>
         <div class="components">
         <div class="header brand-logo-standard-right"></div>
         </div>
    </button>
        <button type="button" class="component" id="add-brand-centered-logo">
            <p>HBrand centered Logo</p>
            <div class="components">
            <div class="header brand-centered-logo"></div>
            </div>
        </button>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: plase add your classes too.

Comment: Thank you Tayfun I forgot it ! I updated the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok finaly I found a solution :

I wrapped the sidebar and the panel inside a div, and the simply target that div to disable all events :

```js
$('.component_panel').mouseleave( function() { 
     $(".component_menu li").removeClass("active");
  $('.modules-panel__list-group').removeClass('slide-lr');
  $('.modules-panel__list-group >div').css({"display":"none"});
    });
```

```html
<div class="flex-col-xs-2 component_panel">
  <div class="component_menu">              
      <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="modules-panel__list-group">
    ...
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change to:

```
.component_menu{
  list-style:none;
  z-index:2;
  background-color:#ffffff;
  padding:10px 0;
  width:200px; //add width what you want
}
.test{ width:400px);
```

and

```
$('.component_menu li').hover(function(){
  $('.component_menu li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  $('.modules-panel__list-group').addClass('slide-lr');
  $('.modules-panel__list-group >div').hide();
  $('.modules-panel__list-group >div').each(function(){
  //$(this).hide();
    if($(this).data('id') == id) {
      
      $(this).css('display','block');
      }
    })
})
$(".test").mouseleave(function() { 
     $(".component_menu li").removeClass("active");
  $('.modules-panel__list-group').removeClass('slide-lr');
  $('.modules-panel__list-group >div').css({"display":"none"});
    });
```

and make a parent div like

```
<div class="test">

** your html code **
</div>
```

Comment: thank you Tayfun, I tried also that way, (mouseenter, mouseleave) but same result, when I hover out of the sidebar, the panel remains open..

Comment: @blogob i tried codeply and worked. Did you add  .component_menu width in css file? here: https://jsfiddle.net/Denizsoft/zdw4395j/1/

Comment: yes, I added it. It's strange because in your example, when I hover outside the sidebar, the panel remains open too..it's not working on my side.

Comment: @blogob i updated code.

Comment: I believe you updated your code once I found my solution, so I can't give you the point. But thanks for your help

Comment: @blogob  I didn't help with points. The important thing was to help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243020/discussion-between-tayfun-yuksel-and-blogob).